# How to find first occurence of character (not from the begining of the string) in cpp ?

Tags: c++, string, find, substring

I have this string :

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file001.docx"
```

I wanted to write a function that gets the name, but It does not seem to work.

First, I used `find` to locate the string `name=`, and then I searched for the first `"` but I'm getting wrong substring. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
    unsigned int start = 0;
    HEADER_NAME = "name="
    start = myString.find(HEADER_NAME);
    if (start != std::string::npos)
    {
        unsigned int pos = 0;
        pos  = myString.find("\"\"", start+ HEADER_NAME.length()  +1);
        std::string name111 = myString.substr(start + HEADER_NAME.length() + 1 , pos - 1);
    }
```

I got :   `file"; filename="file001.docx"` as `name111`

When I used another string : `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request"`
I got : `request"`

`pos` value is always 4 for some reason..

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I can't seem to find what is missing

Thanks a lot

Comment: search for `"name=\""` and add HEADER_NAME.length() to found `start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `string::substr` incorrectly ([string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)).
The fist parameter is the index of the first character of the sub-string and the second parameter is the **length** of the sub-string. You are sending the index of the last character instead. That's why your sub-string reaches the end of the original string.

Try this code:

```
size_t substr_start = static_cast<size_t>(start) + HEADER_NAME.length() + 1;
size_t substr_length = static_cast<size_t>(pos) - substr_start;
std::string name111 = myString.substr(substr_start , substr_length);
```

Instead of

```
std::string name111 = myString.substr(start + HEADER_NAME.length() + 1 , pos - 1);
```